# populating variable elements based on the value of another variable element value in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with some missing values. I want to fill these missing values based on the value of another variable in my dataframe but am not able to work out the code.

```
 library(tidyr)
farm<-  c(1,    1,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4)
region<-    c(NA,   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'Woods')
test<-  c('x',  'y',    'x',    'x',    'y',    'y',     
'x')
i=1:2
j=3
df = data.frame(farm, region, test)
df
```

here is the result

```
  farm region test
1    1   <NA>    x
2    1   <NA>    y
3    2   <NA>    x
4    3   <NA>    x
5    3   <NA>    y
6    3   <NA>    y
7    4  Woods    x
```

I would like to populate region with "mac" if region = 1 or 2 and alternatively populate region with "sto" if region = 3. I have tried the following code:

```
df <- transform(df,region=if (df$farm==i) "mac" else NA)
```

df
to get started but am getting:

```
farm
<dbl>
region
<chr>
test
<fctr>
1   mac x       
1   mac y       
2   mac x       
3   mac x       
3   mac y       
3   mac y       
4   mac x
```

As you can see it is populating "mac" beyond the 1 or 2 variable elements for farm. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: what about when farm==4?

Comment: `with(df, ifelse(farm == 1 | farm == 2, "mac", ifelse(farm == 3, "sto", region)))`

Answer (score 0):

Using base r

```
library(tidyr)
farm<-  c(1,    1,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4)
region<-    c(NA,   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'Woods')
test<-  c('x',  'y',    'x',    'x',    'y',    'y',     
          'x')


df = data.frame(farm, region, test)


df$region <- ifelse(df$farm == 1|df$farm ==2,"mac",
                    ifelse(df$farm == 3, "sto", as.character(df$region)))

df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ifelse to create an extra column

```
df$region <- ifelse(df$farm == 1 | df$farm == 2,'mac',ifelse(df$farm == 3, 'sto',NA))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Is there a way I could use "i" (i.e. i = 1, 2) to save typing out df$farm repeatedly? I have a much larger data frame with many more unique elements?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `df$farm %in% c(1,2)`. When you make a vector to those elements, you can refer instead to that vector: `vec <- c(1,2)` and `df$farm %in% vec`

Answer (score 0):

Using `case_when()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df$region <- case_when(df$farm==1 | df$farm==2 ~ "mac",
                       df$farm==3 ~ "sto",
                       TRUE ~ as.character(df$region))
```